# In Decision Tree Classifier of Scikit-Learn, How to decide the optimal threshold of feature?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

[The decision tree model for Iris Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ppCl.png)

Hi all.

In this figure, a decision boundary of depth=0 is created at 'Petal length'=2.45(cm).

In my opinion, this boundary line will makes the same result about training set even if 'Petal length' is from 2 to 3.

I tried several times by changing the random_state value(of DecisionTreeClassifier class), but when the feature was selected as'petal length' the value was always 2.45(cm).

It may mean that the value can be the optimal threshold of the feature.

How to decide the value of the feature in Scikit-Learn?
does it average of something? or decided by the distribution of samples or range of the feature?

Comment: Looks like sklearn's implementation of the [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html?highlight=tree#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) has a *splitter* parameter that is by default "best", so it looks like there is a determistic way to choose the split value. Maybe you should try to use *splitter*="random" to see if it changes the value?

Comment: @ACo Thanks for answering. I just wanted to know what value or method decides the value (hyperparameter of function in Scikit-Learn) or column that split data, such as 'Petal_lenght' = 2.45. I thought... the function computes all (almost) cases and finds the best (or optimal) value.

Comment: At each step, the algorithm searches among a number of features (i.e. columns), which one will produce the best split. This number of features is set by the *max_features* criterion, see the different possibilities in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html). The quality of the split is evaluated by the *criterion*, here either *gini* or *entropy*. The best split (i.e. the split value) is the one minimizing the criterion. You can read about these [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Gini_impurity)

Comment: @ACo Yeah, I already had read them several times HaHa. Thank you for answering again despite the late comment.